# Paypal button return URL with variables

Tags: paypal

I have added a variable to my PayPal button and it is passing it to PayPal but I have forgotten what to put into the "Add advanced variables" under step 3 of the button creation.  I had this entered in the page before but when I had to change the button the return URL and all variables were removed.  I do not remember where I found the information prior.  An example of the return URL should look like http://example.com/ThanksForYourOrder.cfm?CustomerID=1234

The CustommerID number is sent as a button form field.

Answer (score 0):

You stick it on the URL itself. The only button field you can pass apart from Paypal's define fields is `custom`.

Comment: What do I use as the variable?  I know in ColdFusion I would simply put an outputted form or URL field. ie: CustomerID=#FORM.CustomerID#